# How to create imageview in itemCard of Recyclerview as many as ArrayList size from Firestore? Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml

I want to create imageview as many as arraylist size. I have images arrayList type of String which are image strings from Firestore. I get the data and give it to Recyclerview, but I don't know how to create imageview as size of imageList in item.

**DataClass**

```
    data class AjansGruplariChat(
    val images: ArrayList<String?>,
    val isRead: ArrayList<String?>,
    val message: String,
    val selection: String,
    val sender: String,
    val timeStamp: String)
```

**Firestore Data**

[image]

**Firestore Repo**

```
firebaseFireStore.collection("Agencies").document(docId)
                            .collection("Chat")
                            .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
                                if (error == null) {
                                    val documents2 = value?.documents
                                    if (documents2 != null) {
                                        val list = mutableListOf<AjansGruplariChat>()
                                        for (document2 in documents2) {
                                            val images = document2.get("images") as ArrayList<String?>
                                            val isRead = document2.get("isRead") as ArrayList<String?>
                                            val message = document2.get("message").toString()
                                            val selection = document2.get("selection").toString()
                                            val sender = document2.get("sender").toString()
                                            val timeStamp = document2.get("timeStamp").toString()
                                            val newAjansGrupChat = AjansGruplariChat(images, isRead, message, selection, sender, timeStamp)
                                            list.add(newAjansGrupChat)
                                        }
                                        ajansChatListRepo.value = list
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

**ItemCard**

[image]

Comment: Use a `for` loop and add `ImageView`s programmatically depending on the `images.size`.

Comment: I use for loop as you suggest and it bring me every image string successfully, but I don't know add `ImageView` programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to display the images(list) in side recyclerview.

```
Have you ever heard Recyclerview inside Reyclerview (Nested Recyclerview)?
```

[Here example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-nested-recyclerview-in-android/)